# pagination links not working codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am using the pagination class in my codeigniter application. The pagination links show up fine, ie, I suppose the right number of links eg. 1 2 3 4 5 >, and the page loads up with the amount of entries I specified per page.

The error is when I click on one of the links to go to the next set of entries, it says "page cannot be found".

controller

```
class Testimonials extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('testimonial_model');
        $this->load->library('pagination');
    }

    public function index(){
        $config=[
            'base_url'          =>  base_url('lalcoresidency/testimonials'),
            'per_page'          =>  15,
            'total_rows'        =>  $this->testimonial_model->num_rows(),           
            'full_tag_open'     =>  "<ul class='pagination'>",
            'full_tag_close'    =>  "</ul>",
            'first_tag_open'     =>  '<li>',
            'first_tag_close'    =>  '</li>',
            'last_tag_open'     =>  '<li>',
            'last_tag_close'    =>  '</li>',
            'next_tag_open'     =>  '<li>',
            'next_tag_close'    =>  '</li>',
            'prev_tag_open'     =>  '<li>',
            'prev_tag_close'    =>  '</li>',
            'num_tag_open'      =>  '<li>',
            'num_tag_close'     =>  '</li>',
            'cur_tag_open'      =>  "<li class='active'><a>",
            'cur_tag_close'     =>  '</a></li>',
        ];
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);       
        $result=$this->testimonial_model->get_testimonial($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));        
        $this->load->view('testimonials_view',['result'=>$result]);
    }
}
```

model

```
class Testimonial_model extends CI_Model{

    function get_testimonial($limit,$offset){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('testimonial');
        $this->db->order_by("r_id", "desc");
        $this->db->limit($limit,$offset);
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $result=$query->result();
    }

    public function num_rows(){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('testimonial');
        $this->db->order_by("r_id", "desc");

        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $result=$query->num_rows();
    }
}
```

My website testimonial link is

```
http://localhost/lalcoresidency/testimonials
```

Comment: please help me to find out the solution

Comment: You may need to set some uri routes for your pagination and https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html and try this http://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-with-codeigniter/

Answer (score 2):

You missed `uri_segment` in `$config` and change base_url as below. Try this

```
    class Testimonials extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('testimonial_model');
        $this->load->library('pagination');
    }

    public function index(){
        $config=[
            'base_url'          =>  base_url('testimonials/index'),
            'uri_segment'       => 3,
            'per_page'          =>  15,
            'total_rows'        =>  $this->testimonial_model->num_rows(),           
            'full_tag_open'     =>  "<ul class='pagination'>",
            'full_tag_close'    =>  "</ul>",
            'first_tag_open'     =>  '<li>',
            'first_tag_close'    =>  '</li>',
            'last_tag_open'     =>  '<li>',
            'last_tag_close'    =>  '</li>',
            'next_tag_open'     =>  '<li>',
            'next_tag_close'    =>  '</li>',
            'prev_tag_open'     =>  '<li>',
            'prev_tag_close'    =>  '</li>',
            'num_tag_open'      =>  '<li>',
            'num_tag_close'     =>  '</li>',
            'cur_tag_open'      =>  "<li class='active'><a>",
            'cur_tag_close'     =>  '</a></li>',
        ];
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);       
        $result=$this->testimonial_model->get_testimonial($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));        
        $this->load->view('testimonials_view',['result'=>$result]);
    }
}
```

Comment: vinie ..i try uri_segment in config but showing same error

Comment: 404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.

Comment: where you are getting this error. On click of pagination link ?

Comment: first page is working but when i click link 2 or 3 or 4 then it show..404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.

Comment: can you please tell me what url showing in your browser after click on pagination link

Comment: you missed a change in base url see in my answer i also changed base_url

Comment: it showing same error and now my url showing like this...  http://localhost/lalcoresidency/lalcoresidency/testimonials/index/15

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112048/discussion-between-vinie-and-nushrat).

Comment: remove `lalcoresidency` from base_url

Answer (score 1):

use

```
'base_url'=>  base_url('testimonials/index'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this has something to do with URL rewriting.

first check if

```
http://localhost/lalcoresidency/index.php/testimonials
```

is working.

If so, take a look at config.php:

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

If you enabled mod_rewrite and you want cleaner URLs (like the one you provided) you have to set the above variable to '' and configure an .htaccess as follow:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: http://localhost/lalcoresidency/index.php/testimonials ..this links is working and $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';  in config i removed index.php ..and my .htaccess is

Comment: .htaccess    RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /lalcoresidency  

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|docs|js|system)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /lalcoresidency/index.php?/$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

**Use**

```
'base_url'=>  base_url() . 'testimonials/index/',
```

Comment: if the problem occurs again..check the url of the 404 page.. and change the base url of pagination accordingly..